# Install a program automatically with terminal (which has menus)

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, xorg, xvfb

Is it possible to install a program automatically, which when extracted and run, it opens up a menu installer? (doesn't look like the installer has any options which I can pass in either).

Is there a package out there which can maybe automate pressing the buttons in the menus?

For those interested, the program in question is [CrossWorks for ARM](https://www.rowley.co.uk/arm/index.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually one can try `--quiet, -q --help` but as you said, this will not work here. We have to build something on our own.

For an unattended installation I find it useful to let the installation be run on a virtual X-server. We can send keys to the X-server and will not mess with the current screen. Therefore we need `xvfb` form the X.org project. I also want to take screenshots during the installation to see where the process is at and if any errors occur. We need `imagemagick` for that. Note that imagemagick will only work on X sessions. No wayland support right now.

First download the installer and unpack it.

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://cdn.rowleydownload.co.uk/arm/releases/arm_crossworks_4_1_0_linux_x64.tar.gz
tar xf arm_crossworks_4_1_0_linux_x64.tar.gz
cd ~/Downloads/arm_crossworks_4_1_linux_x64
```

then execute [this script from my gist](https://gist.github.com/ukos-git/5f3370dd40a0ac68cd6ee2e13a675b44):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#
# source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002349/install-a-program-automatically-with-terminal-which-has-menus
# dependencies: sudo imagemagick xvfb

# constants
SERVERNUM=99
SCREENSHOT=status.png
CROSSWORKS_PID=
XVFB_PID=
PROGRESS_PID=
KEYS_PID=

# function find_free_servernum() taken from xvfb-run
# Xvfb is part of x.org and licensed under MIT
# http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
#
# Find a free server number by looking at .X*-lock files in /tmp.
find_free_servernum() {
    # Sadly, the "local" keyword is not POSIX.  Leave the next line commented in
    # the hope Debian Policy eventually changes to allow it in /bin/sh scripts
    # anyway.
    #local i

    i=$SERVERNUM
    while [ -f /tmp/.X$i-lock ]; do
        i=$(($i + 1))
    done
    echo $i
}

start_xvfb() {
    SERVERNUM=$(find_free_servernum)
    echo starting virtual DISPLAY at :$SERVERNUM
    export DISPLAY=:$SERVERNUM

    Xvfb $DISPLAY -screen 0 1280x800x16 &> /dev/null &
    XVFB_PID=$!
}

install_crossworks() {
    check_root
    if [ ! -e ./install_crossworks ]; then
        echo crossworks installation file not found
        exit 1
    fi
    timeout --kill-after=90s 90s sudo -n ./install_crossworks &
    CROSSWORKS_PID=$!

    crossworks_enter_keys &
    KEYS_PID=$!

    show_progress &
    PROGRESS_PID=$!

    if wait $CROSSWORKS_PID; then
        echo ok
    fi

    kill "$PROGRESS_PID" &> /dev/null
    kill "$KEYS_PID" &> /dev/null
}

crossworks_enter_keys() {
    # wait for archive to get checked for crc errors
    sleep 5
    # press next
    xdotool key KP_Enter
    sleep 1
    # accept license
    xdotool key Tab Tab Tab space Tab Tab KP_Enter
    sleep 1
    # select install directory
    xdotool key KP_Enter
    sleep 1
    # start installation
    xdotool key KP_Enter
    sleep 60
    # exit installation
    xdotool key KP_Enter
    sleep 1
}

show_progress() {
    while /bin/true; do
        take_screenshot
        echo -n .
        sleep 1
    done
}

take_screenshot() {
    import -window root $SCREENSHOT
    sudo chown $USER $SCREENSHOT
}

check_root() {
    if ! sudo -n /bin/true 2>/dev/null; then
        echo super user is required for installation.
        sudo /bin/true
    fi
}

check_installation() {
    if [ -e /usr/share/crossworks_for_arm_4.1/bin/crossstudio ]; then
        echo Crossworks installed.
        exit 0
    fi
}

cleanup() {
    kill "$PROGRESS_PID" &> /dev/null
    kill "$CROSSWORKS_PID" &> /dev/null
    kill "$XVFB_PID" &> /dev/null
    kill "$KEYS_PID" &> /dev/null
}

trap cleanup EXIT

check_installation
start_xvfb
install_crossworks
check_installation
```

One big problem was that I was guessing the times the installer takes before the next user input is necessary. It may vary depending on your CPU.

Please also note that the installation script is only valid for *installing* crossworks. The script will not work for *upgrading* or *uninstalling*.

To uninstall crossworks again, execute

```
sudo /usr/share/crossworks_for_arm_4.1/bin/uninstall
```

if there are any errors, try to take a look at the `status.png` that is placed in the current working directory. It is a screenshot from the X framebuffer.

It will look something like this on installation:

[image: status image from screenshot]

Also take a look at `/usr/share/crossworks_for_arm_4.1/`. Sometimes if installation is aborted this directory is there but not completely filled with all the necessary data.

You can try to get the script more advanced, i.e. by capturing status images when a keystroke is required and comparing their checksum some already saved checksums to see at which status the installation is.